# What's most optimal way to find and modify object in array with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of this fashion:

```
var productsList = [
    {   
        id: 'as5',
        name: 'Coca-Cola',
        price: 17.5,
        unit: 'Botellas',
        quantity: 23
    },
    {   
        id: 'q7s',  
        name: 'Queso',
        price: 34.8,
        unit: 'Kilos',
        quantity: 6
    },
    {   
        id: 'pa5',
        name: 'Pan',
        price: 3.5,
        unit: 'Piezzas',
        quantity: 100
    },
    {   
        id: 'capu2',
        name: 'Aceite',
        price: 21,
        unit: 'Botella',
        quantity: 10
    },
    {   
        id: 'bon4',
        name: 'Agua Bonafont',
        price: 25,
        unit: 'Garrafón',
        quantity: 12
    },
    {   
        id: 'tun1',
        name: 'Atún',
        price: 11,
        unit: 'Lata',
        quantity: 30
    },                              
];
```

I need to ***find an array position by its id and decrement quantity property by one***.

This is what I'm doing using lodash 3.10:

```
var product = _.find(productsList, {id: 'tun1'});
product.quantity--;
productsList.splice(_.findIndex(productsList, {id: 'tun1'}), 1, product);
```

But I don't like how I have to perform two operations, one to retrive the modifying array element and other to get its position.

Then I even have to use splice which will iterate again.

What's most optimal way in ES5 JS?

Comment: You don't need the last line. You mutated the object already. All the last line does is replace the object with itself which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had it. The last line is unnecessary and you can actually write it like this:

```
_.find(productsList, {id: 'tun1'}).quantity--;
```

Answer (score 1):

The last step is unnecessary. You don't seem to understand how references work in Javascript (?).

```
product.quantity--;
```

Does what you want.

Comment: Could you extend more on such references nature please?

Comment: In that case, wouldn't `_.find(productsList, {id: 'tun1'}).quantity--;` do the job? However, two steps are much more robust as *find* may not find a suitable value.